# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Requested bean is currently in creation unresolvable circular reference

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, wiremock

I have a source class that apparently break the integration test. The code is provided below.

```
@Configuration
@Import( EmailageConfiguration.class )
public class EmailageServiceConfiguration {

    private static final String EMAILAGE_ACCOUNT_ID_CONFIG_KEY = "emailage.key";
    private static final String EMAILAGE_API_KEY_CONFIG_KEY = "emailage.secret";

    private final EmailageConfigHolder holder;

    public EmailageServiceConfiguration( final EmailageConfigHolder holder ) {
        this.holder = holder;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmailageConfigHolder emailageConfigHolder( Environment env ) {

//        final EmailageConfigHolder holder = new EmailageConfigHolder();

        holder.setApiKey( env.getRequiredProperty( EMAILAGE_API_KEY_CONFIG_KEY ) );
        holder.setAccountId( env.getRequiredProperty( EMAILAGE_ACCOUNT_ID_CONFIG_KEY ) );

        return holder;
    }

}
```

The IT test is provided,

```
public class EmailageServiceIT {

    private static final String EMAILAGE_RESPONSE_FILE = "emailage-response.json";

    private final static String EMAILAGE_ENDPOINT = "/emailage";

    private EmailageService service;

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule( wireMockConfig().dynamicPort() );

    @Before
    @SuppressWarnings( "resource" )
    public void setup() {
        int port = wireMockRule.port();

        System.setProperty( "emailage.uri", "http://localhost:" + port + EMAILAGE_ENDPOINT );
        System.setProperty( "emailage.key", "123" );
        System.setProperty( "emailage.secret", "123" );
        System.setProperty( "emailage.connection_timeout", "10000" );
        System.setProperty( "emailage.read_timeout", "10000" );
        System.setProperty( "kafka.bootstrap_servers", "localhost" );
        System.setProperty( "kafka.topic", "ella-test-topic" );

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( EmailageServiceConfiguration.class );
        service = context.getBean( EmailageService.class );
    }


 // .........................

}
```

When I run the maven command, I get the error stack,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailageServiceConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emailageServiceConfiguration': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at com.ratepay.ella.service.EmailageServiceIT.setup(EmailageServiceIT.java:64)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emailageServiceConfiguration': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at com.ratepay.ella.service.EmailageServiceIT.setup(EmailageServiceIT.java:64)
```

So, the IT test basically breaks in the LOC,

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext( EmailageServiceConfiguration.class );
```

I also add the `EmailageConfigHolder` class for the question,

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class EmailageConfigHolder {

    private String apiKey;
    private String accountId;

}
```

How do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong about this, but

`EmailageServiceConfiguration` is responsible for the creation of the Bean `EmailageConfigHolder` (isn`t that what the @Bean annotation expresses) ?

So how is spring supposed to pass it to the constructor of the object that is supposed to create it? That`s where your circular dependency most likely stems from.

To fix it create an independant producer for your EmailageServiceConfiguration.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add example code snippet based on the question? I tried several options, but, not successful so far.

Comment: I am not that familiar with spring, but if you can provide some more information about the EmailageConfigHolder (and what you require to produce it / for example where you get the environment from?) I might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I added the `EmailageConfigHolder ` in the project

Comment: I guess this is a follow up problem due to code changes made after posting this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56750066/mockito-zero-interactions-with-this-mock I would consider calling the constructor `final EmailageConfigHolder holder = new EmailageConfigHolder();` in your factory method (it is, after all, a factory method for this exact purpose) and rethink the unit test/assertion (as stated in the second paragraph of the accepted answer).

Comment: I agree with @sfiss. If you just changed your code so you can mock it, my suggestion would also be to revert it to the previous code and just verify that the produced holder object contains the correct values.